# Python XPATH and contains for two values?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, appium, xcuitest

The element I am trying to search for looks like this:

```
//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Unseen. Notification (#REGJEWKOEW) Notification Alert System - Code RED bingbong"]
```

Now I need to search for "Unseen" notifications, as I only want new elements, nothing old that has already been "Seen". Alongside this, I want to search for notifications under my name of "bigbong".

```
//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=and contains(., 'bingbong')]
```

^Doesn't work. I'm also not sure how to get it working with two values, instead of just one?

Help is VERY much so appreciated!

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for? It's looking for both "Unseen" and "bingbong" inside the name attribute of the element and works on the example element you posted.

```
//*[contains(@name,'Unseen')][contains(@name,'bingbong')]
```